# How to Open multiple modal windows and have in-modal navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue I assume with ng-include but I am not sure. I will try to describe it as best as possible. Here is little background. I am using modal service from bootstrap, and I have created a view and a controller, that is supposed to serve as a wrapper. Idea is to inject any view in a modal. Here is a html fragment for the "modaltemplate.html"

```
<div data-ng-controller='modalCtrl' >
    <div data-ng-include="templateUrl" >
    </div>
</div>
```

That is it, really nothing to it. Then on the $rootScope I have following code that opens a new modal based on the route name and paramters passed to it.

```
 app.run(function($rootScope,$modal) {
        $rootScope.openEditModal = function (startRouteName, parameters, scope) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'app/common/modaltemplate.html',
                scope: scope,
                controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                    $modalInstance.opened.then(function () {
                    $scope.startRouteName = startRouteName;
                    $scope.routeParams = parameters;

                    });
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

So, when the modal gets opened routeName and parameters get processed in modalCtrl.js. Part of the code was hijacked from angular code base. In nutshell it locates the url for the template to be bound to above ng-include, and sets all parameters to a routeParams on the $scope like this

```
$scope.routeParams = next.params;
//ep: set the templateUrl for the 'view' so that modal.html will load it in.
$scope.templateUrl = next.$$route.templateUrl;
```

This all works great, I am able to open any route, pass paramters, progress between routes back and forth while modal is open etc. Basically, I have a routing within modal working as if it was separate app. For example I can do this

```
var startRouteName = 'InsuredExceptionAdd';
var params = {
       mode: 'add',
        viewTitle: "Add Insured Exception",
        insuredId: insuredId,
};

$scope.openEditModal(startRouteName, params, $scope);
```

and then on save I can navigate to next route etc. Now, I am trying to pop another modal from the modal, and that is where I am running into following issue. A new modal gets poped-up on top of the first, BUT, newly opened modal and the first modal now share the same controller, but not the same instance of the controller. I use quick uid generator just to confirm that the controllers are not the same instace, and they are not. What happens, is that the controller for the included view for the first modal, gets replaced with a controller and the view for the new popped-up modal.
If I look into a DOM I now have two included views. My first view from the first modal is gone and replaced with a new view, and second modal holds same view, but no binding happened. In the example below inInsuredEditCtrl and view have been replaced with a 
inRelatedInsuredEditCtrl like this

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade  in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" ng-transclude="">
            <div data-ng-controller="modalCtrl" class="ng-scope">
            <!-- ngInclude: templateUrl -->
                <div data-ng-include="templateUrl" class="ng-scope">
                    <div id="editRelatedInsured" data-ng-controller="inRelatedInsuredEditCtrl" class="ng-scope">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="lineset ng-binding">Add Related Insured</h3> 
            </div>
            <form role="form" name="editRelatedInsuredForm" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">            
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the one that is now on top of the first modal has correct controller but no binding has happened so the html looks like this

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade  in" ng-class="{in: animate}" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-click="close($event)" modal-window="" index="1" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1060; display: block;">
    <div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content" ng-transclude="">
        <div data-ng-controller="modalCtrl" class="ng-scope">

        <!-- ngInclude: templateUrl -->
        <div data-ng-include="templateUrl" class="ng-scope">
            <div id="editRelatedInsured" data-ng-controller="inRelatedInsuredEditCtrl" class="ng-scope">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="lineset ng-binding">{{routeParams.viewTitle}}</h3> 
            </div>

            <form role="form" name="editRelatedInsuredForm" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">           
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this an issue with ng-include and scopes? I don't know why ng-include gets processed twice and why it affects previous modal. It almost as if change to template url gets passed to both modalCtrl instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out. Had to rewrite some portions, but now it works fine. This controller will allow opening of multiple modals, and will also handle navigation within modal window.

editModal.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.run(function ($modal, $modalStack, $rootScope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $q, $sce, $injector, $http, $templateCache) {

        $rootScope.openEditModal = function (startRouteName, parameters, scope) {

            function afterModalOpened($scope) {

                $scope.title = "modalCtrl";

                // ep: keep track of modal windows open for edit
                // $modalStack keeps list of all opened windows, but that is not good for us
                // saving... and loading... are also modals and they appear as top most window so
                // $modalStack.getTop().value.modalScope.$id does not work always , and in order to 
                // responsed to $locationChangeStart events by top most open edit modal we need this list
                $rootScope.editModalsScopes = $rootScope.editModalsScopes || [];

                $rootScope.editModalsScopes.push($scope);

                console.log("modalCtrl.afterModalOpened -  $scope.$id: " + $scope.$id + " " + "   startRouteName: " + startRouteName);

                //ep: overwrite default implementation os $scope.$close from modal window
                var closeModal = $scope.$close;
                $scope.$close = function (payload) {
                    console.log("scope closing the modal: " + $scope.$id);
                    // $scope.$emit("ModalClosing");
                    offLocationChangeStart();
                    closeModal(payload);
                    $rootScope.editModalsScopes.pop();
                };

                //ep: overwrite default implementation os $scope.$dismiss from modal window
                var dismissModal = $scope.$dismiss;
                $scope.$dismiss = function (reason) {
                    console.log("scope canceling the modal: " + $scope.$id);
                    // $scope.$emit("ModalCanceling");
                    offLocationChangeStart();
                    dismissModal(reason);
                    $rootScope.editModalsScopes.pop();
                };

                //ep: following section deals witn in-modal navigation
                // when we don't want to close window before progressing to a next window
                // one can use $scope.navigateTo(routeName, paramters) to switch the content within the modal window

                var callerLocation = {};
                angular.copy($location, callerLocation);

                //ep: remember the return function so we can de-register it
                var offLocationChangeStart = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {

                    //ep: so that that angular base would not process this also,
                    // navigation is localized to modal window
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var topEditModalScope = $rootScope.editModalsScopes[$rootScope.editModalsScopes.length - 1];

                    console.log("in $locationChangeStart");
                    console.log("    $scope.$id = " + $scope.$id + " " + $scope.title);
                    console.log("    top most edit modal window $scope.$id " + topEditModalScope.$id);
                    console.log("    event.currentScope.$id = " + event.currentScope.$id);
                    console.log("    event.targetScope.$id = " + event.targetScope.$id);

                    //process locationChangeStart events only by the top edit modal window, currently active one
                    if (topEditModalScope.$id !== $scope.$id) {

                        console.log("$locationChangeStart - aborting processing due to scope id diferences");
                        return;
                    }

                    //ep: this could be problematic when there are search parameters and reload is true
                    //but for now it all works fine, address if and when needed
                    if ($location.$$path == callerLocation.$$path) {
                        $scope.$dismiss("back-button");
                    }

                    var route = $location.$$path;

                    console.log("   about to process route " + route);

                    //ep: this will ad entry on the $scope.routeParams and set templateUrl that modal's ng-include is bound to.
                    //  all objects that are on passed will be passed as route paramters. Complex objects will be converted to JSON
                    //  on receiving side one has to convert them back.
                    $q.when(processRoute()).then(function () {
                        console.log("   finished processing route " + route);
                    });
                });

                activate();

                function activate() {

                    $scope.routeParams = parameters;
                    $scope.templateUrl = $scope.getTemplateUrl(startRouteName);

                }

                //ep: this code was lifted from anuglar-route.js/updateRoute() and modified to process 
                //route, get the templateUrl and routeParameters, set them on the $scope, but not raise any events.
                function processRoute() {
                    var next = parseRoute(),
                        last = $route.current;

                    if (next || last) {
                        //forceReload = false;
                        //$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeStart', next, last);
                        //$route.current = next;
                        if (next) {
                            if (next.redirectTo) {
                                if (angular.isString(next.redirectTo)) {
                                    $location.path(interpolate(next.redirectTo, next.params)).search(next.params)
                                             .replace();
                                } else {
                                    $location.url(next.redirectTo(next.pathParams, $location.path(), $location.search()))
                                             .replace();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        $q.when(next).
                          then(function () {
                              if (next) {
                                  var locals = angular.extend({}, next.resolve),
                                      template, templateUrl;

                                  angular.forEach(locals, function (value, key) {
                                      locals[key] = angular.isString(value) ?
                                          $injector.get(value) : $injector.invoke(value);
                                  });

                                  if (angular.isDefined(template = next.template)) {
                                      if (angular.isFunction(template)) {
                                          template = template(next.params);
                                      }
                                  } else if (angular.isDefined(templateUrl = next.templateUrl)) {
                                      if (angular.isFunction(templateUrl)) {
                                          templateUrl = templateUrl(next.params);
                                      }
                                      templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(templateUrl);
                                      if (angular.isDefined(templateUrl)) {
                                          next.loadedTemplateUrl = templateUrl;
                                          template = $http.get(templateUrl, { cache: $templateCache }).
                                              then(function (response) { return response.data; });
                                      }
                                  }
                                  if (angular.isDefined(template)) {
                                      locals['$template'] = template;
                                  }
                                  return $q.all(locals);
                              }
                          }).
                          // after route change
                          then(function (locals) {

                              console.log("processRoute.afterRouteChange $scope.id: " + $scope.$id + " - " + $scope.title);

                              //angular.copy(next.params, $scope.routeParams);

                              //ep: make routeParams available to the next "view" handled by the modal
                              $scope.routeParams = next.params;


                              //ep: set the templateUrl for the 'view' so that modal.html will load it in.
                              $scope.templateUrl = next.$$route.templateUrl;

                              //modalScope.templateUrl = next.$$route.templateUrl;    //^

                              //if (next == $route.current) {
                              //     if (next) {

                              //         next.locals = locals;

                              //           angular.copy(next.params, $routeParams);
                              //     }
                              //     $rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess', next, last);
                              // }
                          }, function (error) {
                              if (next == $route.current) {
                                  //$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeError', next, last, error);
                              }
                          });
                    }
                }

                //ep:copied from anuglar-route.js 
                function parseRoute() {
                    // Match a route
                    var params, match;
                    angular.forEach($route.routes, function (route, path) {
                        if (!match && (params = switchRouteMatcher($location.path(), route))) {
                            match = inherit(route, {
                                params: angular.extend({}, $location.search(), params),
                                pathParams: params
                            });
                            match.$$route = route;
                        }
                    });
                    // No route matched; fallback to "otherwise" route
                    return match || routes[null] && inherit(routes[null], { params: {}, pathParams: {} });
                }

                    /**
               * @param on {string} current url
               * @param route {Object} route regexp to match the url against
               * @return {?Object}
               *
               * @description
               * Check if the route matches the current url.
               *
               * Inspired by match in
               * visionmedia/express/lib/router/router.js.
               */
                //ep:copied from anuglar-route.js 
                function switchRouteMatcher(on, route) {
                    var keys = route.keys,
                        params = {};

                    if (!route.regexp) return null;

                    var m = route.regexp.exec(on);
                    if (!m) return null;

                    for (var i = 1, len = m.length; i < len; ++i) {
                        var key = keys[i - 1];

                        var val = 'string' == typeof m[i]
                              ? decodeURIComponent(m[i])
                              : m[i];

                        if (key && val) {
                            params[key.name] = val;
                        }
                    }
                    return params;
                }

                ////ep: copied from angular-route core
                function inherit(parent, extra) {
                    return angular.extend(new (angular.extend(function () { }, { prototype: parent }))(), extra);
                }

            }

            //ep : open modal and process route and parameters
            $modal.open({
                template: "<div data-ng-include='templateUrl'></div>",
                //templateUrl: 'app/common/modaltemplate.html',
                // scope: scope,
                controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

                    $modalInstance.opened
                                    .then(function () {
                                        afterModalOpened($scope);
                                    });
                }
            });
        };
    });

})();
```